# Proving cluster point sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Below the following question is my solution but I am not sure whether the proofs are correct and rigorously exhaustive so, if present, kindly point out any errors.

Let ${x_n}$ be a convergent sequence with $\underset{n}{\rm lim}$ $x_n =x.$ Consider the set $S=\{ x_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\} \subset \mathbb{R}.$

$(i)$ Assume that $x_n \ne x \hspace{7pt} \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.$ Prove that $x$ is a cluster point of $S$.

$(ii)$ Under the assumption of $(i)$, prove that $x$ is the only cluster point of $S$.

$(iii)$ What happens if the assumption in $(i)$ is removed? Is $x$ necessarily a cluster point? Prove it or provide a counterexample.

Answer:

$(i)$ Let $N$ be any neighbourhood of $x$ then $\exists \epsilon>0$ such that $(x-\epsilon, x +\epsilon) \subseteq N.$ As $\underset{n}{\rm lim}$ $x_n =x, \hspace{7pt} \epsilon>0 \hspace{7pt}\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_n - x|<\epsilon \hspace{7pt}  \forall n \ge n_0 \Rightarrow x_n\in(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon) \hspace{5pt} \forall n \ge n_0 \Rightarrow x_n \in N \hspace{7pt} \forall n \ge n_0$. Hence, every neighbourhood $N$ of $x$ contains an element $S$, other than $x$ so $x$ is a cluster point of $S$.

$(ii)$ We have already shown that $x$ is a cluster point. Let, if possible, $y \ne x$ be any other cluster point and $\epsilon = \frac{|x-y|}{2}$. As $\underset{n}{\rm lim}$ $x_n =x$ then $\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n \in (x-\epsilon, x+ \epsilon) \hspace{6pt} \forall n\ge n_0$. Defining, $\epsilon_n = \frac{|x_n-y|}{2}
\hspace{9pt} n=1,2,..,n_0-1$. Let $\delta$=min$\{\epsilon_1, \epsilon_1,..,\epsilon_{n_0-1},\epsilon\}$ then $(y-\delta, y+\delta) \cap (S\backslash \{y\}) = \varnothing $

Hence $\exists$ a neighbourhood of $y$, namely, $(y-\delta, y+\delta)$ such that it contains no point of $S$ other than $y$ which contradicts the fact that $y$ is a cluster point. So our assumption that $y$ is a cluster point is false and we can conclude that $S$ has only one cluster point i.e $x$

$(iii)$ After the assumption in $(i)$ is removed, $x$ need not be a cluster point of $S$. For example, let $x_n =1 \hspace{6pt} n\in \mathbb{N},$ then $\underset{n}{\rm lim}$ $x_n =1$ and $S=\{1\}$ and it is clear that $S$ has no cluster point.

Answer (score 1):

Your proofs look fine. Here's an alternative proof to *(ii)*.

Let $y\ne x$ be another cluster point of $S$. For each $k\in\mathbb{N}$, note that there are infinitely many $s\in S$ such that the neighborhood $s\in (y-\frac1k,y+\frac1k)$. Hence, one can construct a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ such that $\lim_k x_{n_k} = y\ne x$, which contradicts the fact that $x_n\to x$.